# coffeescript calling server side information

Tags: razor, coffeescript

I am trying to convert my existing java script file into coffee script. One line that gives my headache is

```
var imageSiteUp = '@Url.Content("~/Content/SiteUp.png")';
```

simply putting a

```
imageSiteUp = '@Url.Content("~/Content/SiteUp.png")'
```

into coffee script doesn't do the trick.  I am wondering how this can be achieved.

Comment: That line is correct, I guess you got bitten by the implicit closure stuff.

Comment: I got an error message at next line Error: Parse error on line 34: Unexpected 'INDENT'

Comment: @WeiMa OK... so is the next line indented differently than this one? If they appear to both be indented the same way, check that you aren't using a mix of tabs and spaces.

Comment: The next line indented the exact same way as this line. Actually, I try to put different statement on the next line, and all returns same error.

Comment: @Trevor, Ok I turned on "View whitespace" for visual studio, and discovered that the next line was "indented" as spaces. By replacing the spaces with tab somehow solved the problem. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you have problems like this, it's always a good idea to go into your generated javascript (in the browser using development tools).  That will show the actual logic your browser is running.  This will catch many issues where you may not understand what coffeescript is doing under the hood - including whitespace errors.

Hopefully native coffeescript debugging is on the way:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/08/debug-languages-on-javascript-vm